# framerate of surface updates in camera - android

Tags: android, android-camera

How can i control the frame rate of preview updates in the surfaceView.

I don't implement camera.PreviewCallback

but only get the image captured through the PictureCallback by Camera.takePicture()

PS, I am also not using Camera2 api for backward compatibility.

Comment: Why does this frame rate matter? What is wrong?

Comment: i want the application to get only few frames per second to display so that it can spend most of its resources in image processing task that happens in the background.

Comment: Screen refresh is performed in hardware and does not compete for CPU and memory resources with your app